# Removing old SSH Key on Windows 8 - sublime-text + sftp

Tags: windows-8, ssh, sublimetext2

I need to remove an old ssh key but I don't know the location of the directory. The sublime console says the following.

The SSH host key has changed. This could indicate a potential security breach, or that the domain you are connecting to recently moved servers.
If you are confident this is not a security breach you can delete the old host key and try again.
 1. Win XP: Start > Run > regedit.exe
    Win Vista/7: Start > regedit
 2. Expand to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys and delete the entry including @22:example.com

The Problem is that there is no solution for windows 8 :/

Thanks already for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snipped from ComboFix.org "[How to Open the Registry Editor in Windows 8](http://www.combofix.org/how-to-open-the-registry-editor-in-windows-8.php)":

```
Step 1: If you are on the Windows 8 desktop, point the cursor at the lower right 
corner of the screen. Click the “Search” option as soon as it pops up on the 
left-side of the screen. If you are on the Metro UI Start Screen, point the 
cursor at the lower left corner of the screen and click the right mouse button. 
Now select the “Search” option on the context menu.

Step 2: When you perform either of the above actions, Windows 8 will load 
the “Apps” screen. Type “regedit” into the search bar located on the right 
side of the “Apps” screen.

Step 3: Click the “regedit” search result on the left side of the “Apps” 
screen. If you see a UAC dialog box, click “Yes” to open the 
Windows 8 Registry Editor.
```

After that point, just expand to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys` and delete the desired entry including the @22:domain.tld

Hope this helps.

Comment: stupid me, i always stopped typing at reg because there was just the reg.exe showing up :P
Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasVenturini No worries. Sometimes it just takes a fresh set of eyes.